# Multithreaded program in C: calculating thread stack space

Tags: php, c, multithreading, stack

**Situation:**

I am writing a program in C that maintains a number of threads. Once a thread ends, a new one is created.

Each thread forks - the child runs a PHP process via exec() and the parent waits for it to finish.

Each PHP process takes the next item from a queue, processes it and exits.

**Problem:**

The PHP processes are Symfony tasks and Symfony requires a fairly huge amount of memory.   How can I safely calculate the required stack space for each thread so that PHP processes will have enough memory?

The memory limit set in php.ini is 128Mb so should I allocate this much space in the stack?

Comment: Why do you churn through threads like that? Can't you just get a thread to perform one task after another?

Comment: In this case, each item in the queue is an email, so multithreading makes sense as the bottleneck isn't the CPU but SMTP communication.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP's memory_limit is for heap, not stack.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that each PHP process actually processes x items from the queue (in this case 1000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `fork` you get a new process, when you `exec` the process is replaced by the one you execute. So any setting of stack space in the C program are irrelevant with regards to PHP memory usage.

Comment: Sure - but doesn't it inherit the allocated stack space?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't - you're right: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html

Answer (score 0):

In one way YES.. because, since the PHP.ini is restricting the memory usage/limit to 128 MB, we know that it is the max memory the PHP process is going to use.
So, its better to allocate such space for each thread [ safe side.. double the size of it ].